# Clion: How to properly add images, xml, resources... to cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I tried with copy but doesn't update on each build

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this I used the `configure_file` command in Cmake, so the file is copied to the build directory. It's done every time when the file was modified.

```
configure_file(config.xml config.xml COPYONLY)
```

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/configure_file.html